# Hibernate - One to one relation single table inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, single-table-inheritance

I have 3 entities `BaseFoo`, `FooAbc`, `FooAbcDetail`. `FooAbc` extends base entity `BaseFoo`. I'm trying to do one to one relation between `FooAbc` and `FooAbcDetail`.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = Auditable.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class BaseFoo extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other fields
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseFoo.class)
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class FooAbc extends BaseFoo implements Serializable {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fooAbc",
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              optional = false)
    private FooAbcDetail fooAbcDetail;

    //other fields
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_abc_detail")
public class FooAbcDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id"/* foo_abc_id (I tried both) */)
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @MapsId //also tried @MapsId("id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private FooAbc fooAbc; //also tried BaseFoo

    //other fields
}
```

While project starting up Hibernate throws:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical
>   name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(public.foo_abc_detail) and its
>   related supertables and secondary tables

What is the problem here?

Environment

- Hibernate 5.3.10.Final
- Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: Show how you set up the `foo_abc_detail` table

Comment: @XtremeBaumer sorry I cannot understand. What do you mean by set up? Is it DDL?

Comment: Exactly thats what we need

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sorry I'm late. Here it is.
`CREATE TABLE foo_abc_detail (
    foo_id bigint NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_foo_abc_detail
            PRIMARY KEY
        CONSTRAINT "fk_AwfsRYAAxLwavrnv16Re"
            REFERENCES foo
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
            DEFERRABLE
--other columns
);`

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that there is no column on the `foo_abc_detail` table called `foo_id`.The column on `foo_abc_detail` is just called `id`.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = Auditable.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class BaseFoo extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other fields
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseFoo.class)
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class FooAbc extends BaseFoo implements Serializable {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fooAbc",
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              orphanRemoval = true,
              optional = false)
    private FooAbcDetail fooAbcDetail;

    //other fields
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_abc_detail")
public class FooAbcDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @MapsId //also tried @MapsId("id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private FooAbc fooAbc; //also tried BaseFoo

    //other fields
}
```

Comment: Please provide the column structure of table `foo_abc_detail`

Answer (score 0):

Okey I solved. I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it works! I replaced the `@MapsId` annotation via `@JoinColumn`. Final result of the `FooAbcDetail` class like as below.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_abc_detail")
public class FooAbcDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private FooAbc fooAbc;

}
```